# Unable to find unsafe trait implementation

Tags: rust

I wanted to use [vulkano](https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano) which has all the examples in [a new crate](https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano/tree/master/examples). I copied the folder `examples` out and changed the Cargo.toml to

```
[package]
name = "examples"
version = "0.1.0"
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
vulkano = "0.1.0"
vulkano-win = "0.1.0"
cgmath = "0.7.0"
image = "0.6.1"
winit = "0.5.1"

[build-dependencies]
vk-sys = "0.1.1"
vulkano-shaders = "0.1.0"
```

When I try to build I get:

```
error: the trait bound `(f32, f32, f32): vulkano::pipeline::vertex::VertexMember` is not satisfied [E0277]
) { T :: format (  ) } let dummy = 0usize as * const $ out ; f (
                                                             ^
note: in this expansion of impl_vertex! (defined in <vulkano macros>)
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: required by `<Vertex as vulkano::pipeline::vertex::Vertex>::member::f`
```

The error is located [here](https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano/blob/451fb9c70f64505deddb2fa6ee28c42b68ade56b/examples/src/lib.rs#L18) and the trait is [implemented here](https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano/blob/451fb9c70f64505deddb2fa6ee28c42b68ade56b/vulkano/src/pipeline/vertex.rs#L570-L578).

Why do I get this error? Why does Rust tell me that the trait `VertexMember` is not satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there seemed to be a mismatched version that cargo uses from crates.io. Pointing every dependency to `.git` works.

```
[package]
name = "examples"
version = "0.1.0"
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
vulkano = { git = "https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano" }
vulkano-win = { git = "https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano" }
cgmath = "0.7.0"
image = "0.6.1"
winit = "0.5.1"

[build-dependencies]
vk-sys = { git = "https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano" }
vulkano-shaders = { git = "https://github.com/tomaka/vulkano" }
```